# Pass TextBox values in json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, json.net

**JS :**

```
var Lat = document.getElementById("<%=txt_Lat.ClientID %>").value;
var Long = document.getElementById("<%=txt_Long.ClientID %>").value;
var text = {Lat:Lat,Lng:Long};

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(obj.Lat,obj.Lng);
```

How to pass TextBox values in Json using javascript.

Comment: text is an object already, no need to parse it - and your code is redundant ... just pass Lat, Long instead of obj.Lat, obj.Lng and forget all the cruft with the `text` var

Comment: try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: but I want to pass values using Json, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), you're pretty close. Just skip the `JSON.parse()` method, since `text` already is an object. 
Also, your object names are incorrect (should be lowercase) and you need to pass the values as numeric values to the object:

```
var Lat = parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=txt_Lat.ClientID %>").value);
var Long = parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=txt_Long.ClientID %>").value);
var text = {lat:Lat, lng:Long};

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(text);
```